# Compute correlation coefficient between rows of two matrices

Tags: python, correlation

Given two matrices `A` and `B` in Python, I would like to find the correlation between the rows in two matrices. The matrices would be of length 5*7.

I would like to find the correlation between each row in `A` and `B` and average the correlations:

```
A  = data_All_Features_rating1000_topk_nr ;
B  = data_All_Features_rating1000_leastk_nr ;

corr_1 = corrcoeff(A[0,:],B[0,:]])
corr_2 = corrcoeff(A[0,:],B[1,:]])
corr_3 = corrcoeff(A[0,:],B[2,:]])
corr_4 = corrcoeff(A[0,:],B[3,:]])
corr_5 = corrcoeff(A[0,:],B[4,:]])

corr_6 = corrcoeff(A[1,:],B[1,:]])
corr_7 = corrcoeff(A[1,:],B[2,:]])
corr_8 = corrcoeff(A[1,:],B[3,:]])
corr_9 = corrcoeff(A[1,:],B[4,:]])

corr_10 = corrcoeff(A[2,:],B[2,:]])
corr_11 = corrcoeff(A[2,:],B[3,:]])
corr_12 = corrcoeff(A[2,:],B[4,:]])

corr_13 = corrcoeff(A[3,:],B[3,:]])
corr_14 = corrcoeff(A[3,:],B[4,:]])

corr_14 = corrcoeff(A[4,:],B[4,:]])


corravg = avg(corr_1,corr_2,...,corr_14).
```

This is what I do :

```
topk = 5 
corr_res = []
p = 0 ;
for i in range(0,topk):
    for j in range(i,topk):
        a = data_All_Features_rating1000_topk_nr[i,:]
        b = data_All_Features_rating1000_leastk_nr[j,:]
        tmp = np.corrcoef(a,b)
        print tmp[0,1]
        corr_res = corr_res.extend(tmp[0,1])
```

I get this error:

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-159-ab1d737eed71> in <module>()
     22             tmp = np.corrcoef(a,b)
     23             print tmp[0,1]
---> 24             corr_res = corr_res.extend(tmp[0,1])
     25            # print p+1
     26            # print corr_res

     TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: One of the dimensions is to test different correlation metrics if it is supported by python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficient way to perform matrix operations in python is using of [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) library. Exactly for correlation calculation could be user [numpy.correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html#numpy-correlate) function. To calculate correlation between all combination of rows you could use

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1,3,4,5], [7,8,2,3]])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6, 2], [3,2,4,1], [9,8,2,1]])
corr = []
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(len(B)-i):
        corr.extend(np.correlate(A[i], B[j+i]))
corr_avg = np.average(corr)
print corr_avg
print " ".join(map(str, corr))
```

UPDATE

Instead of

```
print tmp[0,1]
corr_res = corr_res.extend(tmp[0,1])
```

Try

```
print tmp[0,0]
corr_res.append(tmp[0,0])
```

`list` method `extend` taking an iterable object on input (like other list, tuple, ...). And if you want to add to `list` scalar value you should use `append` method.

Comment: Thanks. Nice. However, I think you are calculating the correlation between two rows in two matrices with same index. In my case, I am looking for correlation between all combination of rows. I think the index for the loop should be modified,

Comment: @Yas Could you add short description of your problem with input data example to your question?